# Getting black scans on ground using rtabmap while generating map from point cloud

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, pcl, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am using laser assembler package to convert 2D laser scans to 3D point cloud and then using the point cloud to get a 2D occupancy grid map which can be provided to move base for autonomous navigation but I am getting black scans on the ground. Also the map does not get updated in rviz when I move the robot using teleop but it gets updated in rtabmap viewer. Please can anyone tell me what could be the issue and how this can be solved ? I am using this command - rosrun rtabmap_ros rtabmap -d _subscribe_depth:=false _subscribe_rgb:=false _subscribe_scan_cloud:=true scan_cloud:=/cloud2 odom:=/odom  _approx_sync:=true _queue_size:=500

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393952/getting-black-scans-on-ground-using-rtabmap-while-generating-map-from-point-cloud/) by [Robo_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/90798/robo_guy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2022-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok the problem has got solved, just had to set some of the grid map parameters to a certain value so that the scans do not detect the ground as obstacle and set the parameter "map_always_update" to "true" so that the map keeps updating in rviz while moving the robot using teleop.

---

Originally posted by [Robo_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/90798/robo_guy/) with karma: 115 on 2022-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0